# php one line if statement strange behavior in string

Tags: php, if-statement

Why does the following code print `Five` ?

```
$a = 6;
$b = 'Hey, The Value of $a Is '.
    ($a == 1)?'One':''.
    ($a == 5)?'Five':''.
    ', Period.';
echo $b;
```

Why only `Five`??

Comment: Because $a = 5? What were you expecting?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld : he is getting just `Five` instead of `Hey, The Value of $a Is Five, Period.`, that is the question, I guess.

Comment: @Notulysses - Ok, that would my guess as well, but I don't like guessing games :-) If so is the case, then your answer is great :-)

Comment: The question is not about how to fix the problem, it's why the strange behavior. Take the above code and replace `$a = 5` with `$a = 6`, and `$b` still prints `Five` ... very strange.

Comment: @MarkM Yes, of course. I've already found the fix.

Comment: You should probably post that then

Comment: Fix is not to wrap code like that until you're totally sure it works as intended.

Comment: @MarkM Are you sure? `Five` with `$a = 6`? see https://eval.in/152603 the out put is as expected.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Post which?

Comment: @Webinan I'm positive. I said using the code in your question, not the fixed code: https://eval.in/152610

Comment: @MarkM Ahh sorry, Yes!

Comment: @MarkM - I've added a comment to my answer, you are reading code wrong, beginning of the string gets evaluated as well as ($a == 1) and gets converted to false, and therefore vanishes. Use the () as Notulysses told you.

Comment: @hidden_4003 Yes, I understand that the `()` are necessary to make the logic work as intended - I was trying to figure out what was going on with the code as it is. I get it now, your answer makes more sense with the additional comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should use `()` for each *shorthand  if statement*:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 'Hey, The Value of $a Is '.
(($a == 1) ? 'One' : '') . (($a == 5) ? 'Five' : '') .
', Period.';
echo $b;
```

It is happening so because $b is assigned at first to the `'Hey, The Value of $a Is '`, then to the `One`(as shorthand if syntax is not valid), after that it is assigned to `Five` (again, by coincidence as it stays the first) and as (again) syntax is not valid the value is not concatenated with `',Period.'`. So, to sum up, this string is just an order of three assignments and as the third is `Five` then it is printed in the browser.

[**Example**](https://eval.in/152577)

Comment: Yes, I'v just found that, yet curious why only `Five`?

Answer (score 0):

So we take the code, make it 1 line

> $b = 'Hey, The Value of $a Is '.($a == 1)?'One':''.($a == 5)?'Five':''.', Period.';

Remove redundant .

> $b = 'Hey, The Value of $a Is '.($a == 1)?'One':**($a == 5)?'Five':', Period.'**;

So $a = 5 means the part shown in bold is executed:

> ($a == 5)?**'Five'**:', Period.'

Now since $a = 5 only shown part gets executed again, thus we only get 'Five'.

Comment: Because what gets evaluated is "'Hey, The Value of $a Is '.($a == 1)" not the "($a == 1)" as you would think. Didn't make it clear enough in the answer. So after first ternary is evaluated you only left with "($a == 5)?'Five':', Period.'"